# VB.Net New Objects: Where do they go?

Tags: vb.net, object, new-operator

Every once and a while, I have to get the basics to a language after long coding excursions.  In VB.Net, I understand declarying a variable as an object type more or less creates a reference to it.

Take the following code:

```
Dim obj1 as Object
Dim obj2 as Object
obj1 = new Object
obj2 = new Object
obj1 = obj2
```

A very elementary set of tasks, but I am trying to figure out what exactly is going each step of the way.  This is my understanding: Line 1, obj1 is declared as an Object type and the compiler creates a reference for obj1 to hold, but **what is obj1 referencing at the end of line 1?**(are `nothing` and `null` synonymous?)  Line 2 is the same as line 1 except its a different variable.  Line 3, the compiler allocates space in the heap for a new object and passes the reference to obj1 1 to hold.  Line 4 is the same as line 3.  The part that I've never been quite clear on is the the 5th line.  obj1 is assigned to the same reference as obj2 so they are both pointing the same object in memory.  So what happens to the object that obj1 was originally assigned in line 3?  **Once obj1 takes the same reference as obj2, does that leave the first new object left in memory with no way to access it** (or at least until garbage collection starts)**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is obj1 referencing at the end of line 1?

In VB parlance it's pointing to `Nothing`, which is the same as C#'s `null` (which in this instance you can think of as pointing to memory location zero).

> Once obj1 takes the same reference as obj2, does that leave the first
>   new object left in memory with no way to access it (or at least until
>   garbage collection starts)

Yes, that's exactly what happens.  With the vagaries of garbage collection, you can never tell  when this will actually be collected, and indeed, there is no guarantee that it will ever be collected.

Let the GC worry about that sort of stuff, don't try to "help" it, unless you really (and dude I seriously mean *really*) need to.

Comment: All great answers, but the answer given here best fits the question.

Answer (score 3):

First up is null/Nothing question.  The value of obj1 and obj2 before the new objects are created is `Nothing`, but this is not precisely the same as C#'s `null`.  VB.Net's `Nothing` is a closer analog to C#'s `default(T)` concept. In this case it all comes to the same thing, but it's worth knowing the distinction because `null` and `Nothing` behave very differently when you're working with value types.

The next thing to understand here is the assignment in line 5. At this point, the reference from the obj2 variable is *copied* to the obj1 variable.  This is important because they are no longer the same reference, but rather two references that happen to point (refer) to the same place. This is easy enough to understand in this code, but I've seen it trip people up in more complex places... say one of the variables is assigned in a method.

The final point is that, yes, the object originally referred to by the obj1 variable is now eligible for garbage collection. You don't need to worry about it any more.

Comment: Interesting to note C#'s `default (T)`

Answer (score 1):

After line 1, `obj1` will hold a reference to the `null` value - `Nothing`.

`Nothing` in VB.NET is the same as `null` in C#, at least when it comes to reference types (see the comment by Joel Coehoorn).

Line 5 - the object that `obj1` references to is the some one that `obj2` references. At this point the first object is indeed no longer accessible and will get garbage collected.

Comment: Nothing in VB.net is only the same as Null in C# for reference types. Nothing is actually a closer match for C#'s `default(T)`

Answer (score 1):

In .net when you create a variable you create a reference or a value type.  All of your examples are reference variables when the program enters the function it creates the necessary space to hold the locals (ie the space necessary to hold references).

---

ILdasm

```
.method public static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       32 (0x20)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] object obj1,
           [1] object obj2)
  IL_0000:  nop
```

It then create objects on the managed heap not the "heap" and assigns them to the locals.

```
 IL_0001:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  call       object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
  IL_000b:  stloc.0
  IL_000c:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0011:  call       object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
  IL_0016:  stloc.1
  IL_0017:  ldloc.1
  IL_0018:  call       object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
  IL_001d:  stloc.0
```

The function then returns

```
 IL_001e:  nop
  IL_001f:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Mai
```

The Garbage collector is invoked by the whim of the runtime( you can force its hand) and will collect all of the unreachable objects by generation.

Comment: Sorry, I hate to be a pedant (_who am I kidding!_) but "and will collect all of the unreachable objects by generation" is actually "and will _try to_ collect all of the unreachable objects by generation". There's no guarantee a GC run will collect anything, even objects eligible for collection.